# VC dimension and two definitions, which of them is correct?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, vc-dimension

Are these two definition is contrast to each others?

[image: "one]

> option (4) says cannot shatter "one of..." says one... but other
> slides as follows tells us "no set of k+1 points..."

[image]

which of them is true for definition of VC ... which part is my wrong point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct definition is the second one (and the answer (3) from the first part of your question). To quote an authoritative source:

> The final ingredient in the Vapnik Chervonenkis theory is an analysis of the case when there is a finite $d$ which is the largest size of shattered set [...] The value $d$ is known as as the Vapnik Chervonenkis (VC) dimension of the class $H$, denoted by VCdim($H$).

(Cristianini and Shawe-Taylor, **An Introduction to Support Vector Machines and other kernel-based learning methods**, Cambridge University Press 2000, p. 56.)

However, the "definition" you quote in the first part of your question is actually not a definition, but seems to be an exam question. One part of it is about the "*most efficient*" way of proving the dimensionality of a given learner. Apparently, the teacher who has asked this question thinks that it is easier (more *efficient*) to show that at least one set of N+1 points cannot be shattered, than showing it for all.